# Casting between void* and a class reference in D

Tags: object, pointers, casting, d

What is the correct way to cast back and forth between a `void*` pointer and a class value in D, the first or the second?

1. `cast(ClassName)voidPointer` and `cast(void*)this`
2. `cast(ClassName*)voidPointer` and `cast(void*)this`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the first. A class reference is already a pointer on the inside, so you want to cast directly in it.